# Peer-to-peer over Internet on Qt

Tags: qt, p2p, qtcpsocket, qtnetwork, nat-traversal

I need to make peer-to-peer communication between applications.

The applications also shall find each other automatically in internet. For this, among other things, I need to overcome `NAT Traversal`, etc.

As example, I need to use the communication something like following:

```
InternetPeer peer;

peer.setName("my_name");

peer.listen(); // accept connections
peer.startSearchForOthers(); // find another peers

connect(&peer, &InternetPeer::newConnection, this, ...);

connect(&peer, &InternetPeer::anotherPeerFound, this, ...);

QStringList peerNames = peer.availablePeers();

peer.sendMessage(peerNames.at(0), "Hello");

peer.close();
```

Then it would be good to have some way to access such a connection with `QTcpSocket` or `QUdpSocket`.

How this can be done on Qt and c++?

Comment: Start with a simpler project. Write some code to have two copies of your app exchange messages. You can find a sample QT chat app online which will help you understand the processes.

Comment: @johnelemans I know about Qt chat examples, but have no adea how to connect over internet

Comment: The problem here is really the p2p part rather than anything to do with Qt.  To that end you might want to look at using an IP multicast announce/discover mechanism such as [avahi](https://www.avahi.org/).

Comment: Look more closely, if you set up a chat over IP then just use a remote IP address. Same thing!